# How to load an html file along with its styles into a browser API

Tags: html, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a web application in Asp.Net Core using API. I am stuck with an issue that I am not able to load an HTML file through API into the web application. I tried to load HTML in the following way

```
var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/HelloWorld.html"));
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StringContent(fileContents.ToString());
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return response;
```

in the API controller but did not successful. The HTML file is located in an external directory with its supporting css files.
Can anyone help me to load the file into a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpResponseMessage` is for Legacy ASP.NET MVC Web API, in ASP.NET Core Web API you can do it like below:

**Controller:**

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public TestController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetHtml")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Content", "Hello.html");
        var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
        return File(fileStream, "text/html");
    }
}
```

The static file should under **wwwroot** folder

[image]

Reference the .css file in the html file:

**Hello.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/MyCss.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyCss.css:**

```
h1{
    color: black
}
h2{
    color:rebeccapurple
}
h3 {
    color: greenyellow
}
h4 {
    color: salmon
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mj1313. I have checked it but the style is not getting. Is there any way to load the style files ?

Comment: Hi @AnonymousDev, you need to reference your css file in your html file, I have update my answer.